# How to format bespoke struct, so that it appears like Vector3 in Unity Editor inspector?

Tags: unity

I have a bespoke struct, which has XYZ variables just like Vector3, but unlike Vector3, the inspector does not display them neatly and horizontally. I have tried to read documentation and copy Vector3 to no avail. Please tell me how to make my custom struct display XYZ in the inspector exactly like Vector3. Below is a screenshot from the Unity editor to show the difference ("Test" is a Vector3, Position is my own class).

[image: capture from inspector]

Comment: The search term is `CustomPropertyDrawer`, google gives https://forum.unity.com/threads/making-a-proper-drawer-similar-to-vector3-how.385532/

Answer (score 1):

As Zibelas noted, you can use a custom property drawer. However, let's analyze *why* you are making a custom struct with the same fields as a `Vector3` (or **why you probably shouldn't**).

If your struct functions exactly the same as a `Vector3` (or `Vector3Int`), there's no point in using it over `Vector3`, since Unity's APIs make extensive use of `Vector3`.

If your struct behaves like a `Vector3` but adds *new functionality*, you should strongly consider using extension methods or helper functions instead. For example, let's imagine you want a way to swap the X and Y values for some reason. One way to do this is with [extension methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static void SwapXY(ref this Vector3 v3) {
        float temp = v3.x;
        v3.x = v3.y;
        v3.y = temp;
    }
}
```

This adds a new function to `Vector3` which we can use like any other function! Note that I used the `ref` keyword because `Vector3` is a value type and in this example we're modifying the original value.

```
Vector3 test = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
test.SwapXY();
Debug.Log(test); //(2.0, 1.0, 3.0)
```

Alternatively, we can use static helper functions:

```
public static class Vector3Helpers {
    public Vector3 SwapXY(Vector3 value) {
        return new Vector3(value.y, value.x, value.z);
    }
}
```

So when *should you* consider creating your own struct?

- **To make the struct immutable**. `Vector3` is mutable (its fields can be changed after it is created). Mutable structs are generally discouraged in C#, but Unity makes extensive use of mutable structs for debatable reasons I won't get into here.
- **For type safety**. For example, if a function argument expects a position and you want to be sure you don't accidentally pass in a `Vector3` representing euler angles, you could make a `Position` struct that's otherwise identical to `Vector3`.
- If you want to **change how `Vector3`'s existing functions work** (I can't think of any reason you'd want to do this)
- If you want to **add new fields**, or implement other new functionality that can't be accomplished with extension methods.
- **To make the struct serializable**. That doesn't directly apply here because `Vector3` is *already* serializable, but standard structs built into C# like `TimeSpan` are not compatible with Unity's serialization system.
- **To change the precision** (e.g. use doubles instead of floats)

Comment: I think this post has some useful resources, but to be an answer to the question that was asked, it should also at least briefly show how to use the CustomPropertyDrawer.